# How to reference tables in a GeoPackage after changing layer name in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-expression, layer-name

While developing a Geodatabase with a lot of tables, reports etc. I decided to rename some layers in QGIS to help my client use the database.

Now all my expressions like `get_feature()` won't work because of the change.

In Layer Properties/Information there is the Name (the name which I changed to, like *RenamedLayer*) and then there is the source which ends with `"....\....\database.gpkg|layername=OriginalNamedLayer"`

How can I reference the tables/layers as used in the GPKG? And without the path to it...so I can copy the db and it will still work on another pc.

Comment: Did the layers persist in a project throughout the change? If so, you can use the layer id, which remains the same, even if the layer name changes. In the expression editor, expand the `Map Layers` section and double-click a layer name to add the id to the expression.

Comment: @matt No, they dont. The main problem is there are a lot of fields in the table and there are a lot of new fields. So every time i add a new field it will be the last field. But there has to be some kind of order so people who fill the table will find the right field fast. To maintain the order i use "refactor fields" and it will create a whole new layer (with a new ID)

Comment: @Stefan I have come to the point, where I start not to care about the field order anymore. Ignore it and use the field order settings for the attribute tables instead. Make use of attribute forms and all the other shebang to make it easier for users to work with the data.
When you project has reached some final stage, you can still reorder the fields to you likings. Just my 2 cents.